# Rust joining thread cannot guarantee correct lifetime

Tags: multithreading, rust, closures

I tried to create a simple example with threads:

```
let str = String::from("string");
let thread1 = thread::spawn(|| { //error: may outlive borrowed value `str`
    println!("{}", str);
});
thread1.join();
```

Since I call `thread1.join()` there is no way that the closure may outlive the borrowed value `str`. Is there a way to tell rust compiler about it somehow or the only way is to `move` ownership?

Comment: Use [scoped threads](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.scope.html) for that.